# using the command line in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: command-line

How do I use the `run` command (I assume it is used on the terminal). for example, I received an instruction to run `/opt/COMODO/post+setup.sh --`  then, after that i would do `etc/init.d/cmdavd restart`...my problem is that I cannot get the terminal to accept a run command.  Thank you, Richard Volta

Comment: There is no `run` command.  What exactly did you enter on the command line?  What error message was returned?

Comment: On a sidenote, it seems like you're trying to install comodo antivirus, i assure you there is no need for an antivirus in linux. Commodo will only be able to deal with window's virus which can't affect you at all in linux.

Comment: I had used CLAMSCAN. It found that computer was infected with INF.autorun-32, but wouldn't/couldn't eliminate the worm.  That's what started me reinstalling COMODO.

Comment: @Richard windows virus can't affect your linux installation. Clamscan might detect viruses, but it will only be able to infect windows installation. Linux, you could say is in a way immune to viruses. Rootkits do exist however, but very rare. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Zachree1 also said there is no `run` in linux. What you need is `./`.  In linux, if you want to execute a file you make it have executable permission and put `./` before it to run. In your case you will have to do

First make it executable

```
sudo chmod a+x /opt/COMODO/post+setup.sh
```

Then run it

```
cd /opt/COMODO/
./post+setup.sh
```

Put a `sudo`  in front of command if it says `Operation not permitted` or `Permission Denied`.

After that, since `cmdavd` is inside `/etc` you will require sudo permissions, so command would be,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cmdavd restart
```

Hope that clears it up

Answer (score 0):

To run something in the terminal you just type it in. In your case: `/opt/COMODO/post-setup.sh` and then `/etc/init.d/cmdavd restart`. Puttin `sudo` before both commands is also probably best.

There is no command to run something in the terminal, you just run it by typing its path.